# xamarin forms signing package failed android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I try to distribute xamarin forms android application using ad hoc I receive the following error:

> Signing package failed,  Missing input apk

What should I do to resolve this ,previous projects works fine ,the problem only with this one.

Comment: Need more details than just one line error message for someone to help you

Comment: @Prateek I dont have any more information.
I created a new project ,didn't touch the android settings, archieved the project, and when I try to distribute using Ad Hoc I get the error I wrote before.

I don't have any idea why it's not working and I don't know what this error mean, I checked the obj release folder and the apk exist.
The only solution I see now is to create new project and hope it won't happen again.

Comment: How are packing the apk..the steps? where is this error shown?  is there a log? what keystrore did you use,is it valid one?

Comment: @Prateek I didn't use a keystore, I clicked the 'archive' option in visual studio , thats the way I generated the apk and I used this way for any application I made.
The apk generated successfully but when I try to distribute it the error I mentioned is shown.

Comment: @Prateek I want to fix something I wrote,
I generated the android keystore using Visual studio like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows

I tried to create a new one but it didn't help

Comment: Did you sign the apk with same certificate? make note of where you save it, it opens explorer before entering password, just save it on desktop because there is another unsigned version at **...../archives** folder